# React Native ignores flexDirection

Tags: css, react-native

My React Native app does weird layouting. flexDirection "row", "column" and "row-reverse" is completely the same. When I do "column-reverse" it only shows one square. wtf.

[image]

[image]

Comment: instead of display: 'flex'  use flex: 1

Comment: thanks but doesn't work. I noticed that the problem only occurs when a component is imported.